# What does the 'J' icon on a photo in the Photos app mean?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, photos.app

For some reason on some of my photos there is this 'J' icon:

[image]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Source](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3843605):

> When you shoot RAW + JPEG the Photos app stacks the two images together. The J means you have a stack with a JPEG file and a RAW file and the JPEG file is used as original. To change to the RAW file go into edit mode (enter) and choose Image - > Use Raw as original. The letter will now change to a R.